# Calculate Rolling Return

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have data that looks like this:

```
                 Close
Date
2022-06-01  148.710007
2022-05-31  148.839996
2022-05-27  149.639999
2022-05-26  143.779999
2022-05-25  140.520004
2022-05-24  140.360001
2022-05-23  143.110001
2022-05-20  137.589996
2022-05-19  137.350006
2022-05-18  140.820007
2022-05-17  149.240005
.....
```

I want to calculate the `rolling` return (rolling percent change) over a `window` of length `wind` for the whole `column` `Close` in the `dataframe`. I tried this but I get a weird output:

```
df = closing_data.pct_change(periods=wind, axis=0).dropna(1)
```

The result is not what I expected:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2022-06-01 00:00:00, 2022-05-31 00:00:00, 2022-05-27 00:00:00, 2022-05-26 00:00:00, 2022-05-25 00:00:00, 2022-05-24 00:00:00, 2022-05-23 00:00:00, 2022-05-20 00:00:00, 2022-05-19 00:00:00, 2022-05-18 00:00:00, 2022-05-17 00:00:00, 2022-05-16 00:00:00, 2022-05-13 00:00:00, 2022-05-12 00:00:00, 2022-05-11 00:00:00, 2022-05-10 00:00:00, 2022-05-09 00:00:00, 2022-05-06 00:00:00, 2022-05-05 00:00:00, 2022-05-04 00:00:00, 2022-05-03 00:00:00, 2022-05-02 00:00:00, 2022-04-29 00:00:00, 2022-04-28 00:00:00, 2022-04-27 00:00:00, 2022-04-26 00:00:00, 2022-04-25 00:00:00, 2022-04-22 00:00:00, 2022-04-21 00:00:00, 2022-04-20 00:00:00, 2022-04-19 00:00:00, 2022-04-18 00:00:00, 2022-04-14 00:00:00, 2022-04-13 00:00:00, 2022-04-12 00:00:00, 2022-04-11 00:00:00, 2022-04-08 00:00:00, 2022-04-07 00:00:00, 2022-04-06 00:00:00, 2022-04-05 00:00:00, 2022-04-04 00:00:00, 2022-04-01 00:00:00, 2022-03-31 00:00:00, 2022-03-30 00:00:00, 2022-03-29 00:00:00, 2022-03-28 00:00:00, 2022-03-25 00:00:00, 2022-03-24 00:00:00, 2022-03-23 00:00:00, 2022-03-22 00:00:00, 2022-03-21 00:00:00, 2022-03-18 00:00:00, 2022-03-17 00:00:00, 2022-03-16 00:00:00, 2022-03-15 00:00:00, 2022-03-14 00:00:00, 2022-03-11 00:00:00, 2022-03-10 00:00:00, 2022-03-09 00:00:00, 2022-03-08 00:00:00, 2022-03-07 00:00:00, 2022-03-04 00:00:00, 2022-03-03 00:00:00, 2022-03-02 00:00:00, 2022-03-01 00:00:00, 2022-02-28 00:00:00, 2022-02-25 00:00:00, 2022-02-24 00:00:00, 2022-02-23 00:00:00, 2022-02-22 00:00:00, 2022-02-18 00:00:00, 2022-02-17 00:00:00, 2022-02-16 00:00:00, 2022-02-15 00:00:00, 2022-02-14 00:00:00, 2022-02-11 00:00:00, 2022-02-10 00:00:00, 2022-02-09 00:00:00, 2022-02-08 00:00:00, 2022-02-07 00:00:00, 2022-02-04 00:00:00, 2022-02-03 00:00:00, 2022-02-02 00:00:00, 2022-02-01 00:00:00, 2022-01-31 00:00:00, 2022-01-28 00:00:00, 2022-01-27 00:00:00, 2022-01-26 00:00:00, 2022-01-25 00:00:00, 2022-01-24 00:00:00, 2022-01-21 00:00:00, 2022-01-20 00:00:00, 2022-01-19 00:00:00, 2022-01-18 00:00:00, 2022-01-14 00:00:00, 2022-01-13 00:00:00, 2022-01-12 00:00:00, 2022-01-11 00:00:00, 2022-01-10 00:00:00, 2022-01-07 00:00:00, ...]
```

Comment: Mind posting what is it that you want as output?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you should do, `dropna` with `axis = 1` will drop the whole column when there is NaN

```
df = closing_data.pct_change(periods=wind, axis=0).dropna(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. Is there  a way to see the index and the return for that index. So say first 180 day window, return = whatever, next 180 day window, return whatever?

Comment: @Ivan what you mean by 180 day window return whatever ?

Comment: BENY, I mean can I see the the rolling return for each period, e.g. first period = x. the rolling return for the second period = y, and so on.

Comment: With a window of 180 days, that might be from 5/31/2015 - 1/1/2016, then the next is 6/1/2015 - 1/2/2016 and so on. I need to see each periods Return.

Comment: Sheesh, I hope I understand what data.pct_change(period ) does.....I am assuming it is a rolling return type calculation.

Comment: @Ivan you mean you want something like df.rolling() right ?

Comment: BENY, Yes! And I want to see each period range and what it's corresponding return is

Comment: @Ivan something like `df['Close'].rolling('180 D').apply(lambda x : (x[0] - x[-1])/x[0])
` ?

Comment: Ideal output is say a dictionary, {[5/31/2016, 1/1/2017], -.18} and so on

Comment: @Ivan output in comment can be easy translate to what you need, just out.index + 180 days

Comment: @Ivan and also would you mind change your question , cause this is more like different question from your original posted

Comment: BENY, what do you recommend the title be?